# Click_button in RSpec causes 'Missing required keys: [:id]'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, capybara

This is my spec file where I want to test adding players:

```
RSpec.describe "AddPlayers", type: :request do
  describe "add player" do
    let(:player) { FactoryGirl.create :player }
    it "add new player with valid data" do
      visit new_player_path
      fill_in "player_firstname", with: player.firstname
      fill_in "player_lastname", with: player.lastname
      fill_in "player_nickname", with: player.nickname

      click_button "Add player"
    end
  end
end
```

And when I run test I get:

> ```
>  Failure/Error: click_button "Add player"
>  ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
>    No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"players", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]
> ```

My FactoryGirls named `players.rb` looks like here:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :player do
    firstname "John"
    lastname "Smith"
    nickname "smithy99"
    avatar { File.new(Rails.root.join('spec/images/1.png')) }
  end
end
```

My Controller looks like here:

```
  def new
    @player = Player.new
  end

  def create
    @player = Player.create(player_params)
    redirect_to player_path(@player)
  end
```

And my `Player` model:

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :nickname, presence: true, uniqueness: true;
  validates :firstname, :lastname, presence: true;
  has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }
  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

  def full_name
    "#{firstname} #{lastname} (#{nickname})"
  end
# other custom methods...
end
```

And when I go in my browser to link:

> http://localhost:3000/players/new

and click "Add Player" without filing input fields I get the same error like in RSpec:

> No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"players", :id=>nil}
>   missing required keys: [:id]

So my question is what is the problem with my spec and how to deal with it? Why `player` created by FactoryGirl has not `id`?

Comment: Can you add your Player model code? Also can you try using Player.create! to see any errors?

Comment: Yes, I have the same when I tried using Player.create! in my spec. I added code for Player model.

Comment: Can you post the ouput of ` @player = Player.create!(player_params)
    puts @player.errors` in the controller?

Comment: Problem solved. In my controller I had `@player = Player.create(player_params)` not `@player = Player.create!(player_params)` and it looks like it caused problem. When I changed it everything works. Thanks!